# If $A$ is a normal matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ and all the eigenvalues of $A$ are real, is $A$ always symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is idoes  $A$ always symmetric?

I know that if $A$ is normal it is diagonalizable, but does the fact it has only real eigenvalues make it symmetric?

Comment: If it is normal, then over the complex there is a unitary $U$ and a diagonal $D$ such that $A=UDU^*$, where $D$ is diagonal with the eigenvalues of $A$ in it. Then $A^T=(U^*)^TD^TU^T=\overline{U}D\overline{U^*}$. If the eigenvalues are real, then you get further equalities $=\overline{U}\overline{D}\overline{U^*}=\overline{UDU^*}=\overline{A}$. Since $A$ is real, then $\overline{A}=A$.

Comment: If you're working over $\mathbb{R}$ only, then you can have matrices with no eigenvalues because the eigenvalues would have to be complex. Technically, such a matrix has only real eigenvalues. And yet, there are such matrices that are not symmetric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

$A$ is normal so it diagonalizes in an orthonormal basis $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ with $Ae_i = \lambda_i e_i$. By assumption we have $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then for $x = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle x, e_i\rangle e_i$ and $y = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle y, e_i\rangle e_i$ we have

\begin{align}
\langle Ax,y\rangle &= \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n \langle x, e_i\rangle \lambda_i e_i, \sum_{i=1}^n \langle y, e_i\rangle e_i\right\rangle \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \langle x, e_i\rangle \langle e_i, y\rangle \lambda_i \\
&= \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n \langle x, e_i\rangle  e_i, \sum_{i=1}^n \langle y, e_i\rangle \lambda_ie_i\right\rangle \\
&= \langle x, Ay\rangle
\end{align}

so $A^* = A$.